# Time out on drive.mount('/content/drive') in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using google colab and there is always time out when I run the command

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I have restarted runtime as well but nothing changed. 
Although it was working yesterday.

Here is the error:

> TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
>   
>   command: /bin/bash
>   args: [b'/bin/bash', b'--noediting']
>   buffer (last 100 chars): 'ZI [91298688] ui.cc:80:DisplayNotification Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped\r\n'
>   before (last 100 chars): 'ZI [91298688] ui.cc:80:DisplayNotification Drive File Stream encountered a problem and has stopped\r\n'
>   after: 
>   match: None
>   match_index: None
>   exitstatus: None
>   flag_eof: False
>   pid: 3135
>   child_fd: 76
>   closed: False
>   timeout: 120
>   delimiter: 
>   logfile: None
>   logfile_read: None
>   logfile_send: None
>   maxread: 1000000
>   ignorecase: False
>   searchwindowsize: None
>   delaybeforesend: 0.05
>   delayafterclose: 0.1
>   delayafterterminate: 0.1
>   searcher: searcher_re:
>       0: re.compile('google.colab.drive MOUNTED')
>       1: re.compile('root@32155b861949-0ddc780f6f5b40478d01abff0ab81cc1: ')
>       2: re.compile('(Go to this URL in a browser: https://.*)\r\n')`

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of timeouts is having many thousands of files or folders in your root Drive directory.

If that's the case for you, my recommendation is to move some of these items into folders in your root directory so that the root has fewer items.

Under the covers, the way that Drive works requires listing the entire root directory to mount it as a FUSE filesystem, which takes time proportional to the number of files and folders you have, which leads to timeouts if you have many files and folders.

Comment: Thank you, and one more thing. I used the code from [Here](https://medium.com/@move37timm/using-kaggle-api-for-google-colaboratory-d18645f93648) to install kaggle cli on drive. Is there any issue because of this?

Answer (score 0):

Why does drive.mount() sometimes fail to say "timed out", and why do I/O operations in drive.mount()-mounted Do folders sometimes fail?

Google Drive operations can time out when the number of files or sub-folders in a folder grows too large. If thousands of items are directly contained in the top-level "My Drive" folder then mounting the drive will likely time out. Repeated attempts may eventually succeed as failed attempts cache partial state locally before timing out. If you encounter this problem, try moving files and folders directly contained in "My Drive" into sub-folders. A similar problem can occur when reading from other folders after a successful drive.mount(). Accessing items in any folder containing many items can cause errors like OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error (python 3) or IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error (python 2). Again, you can fix this problem by moving directly contained items into sub-folders.

Note that "deleting" files or sub-folders by moving them to the Trash may not be enough; if that doesn't seem to help, make sure to also Empty your Trash. [For your Reference](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what you are pasting if its the token that is being generated?
I had this issue and the copy to the clipboard was copying the link, not the token.
you might want to manually copy it.